# How to specify a marker Icon URL?

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to change the Leaflet default Icon; in my script I set

```
L.Icon.Default.prototype.options.iconUrl = 'Point.png';
```

The .png file is in the same folder than my script file but I get a broken image icon, the .png is not found.

How can I specify the right .png location ?

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools, network section, to check what URL is being requested.

Comment: Browser expects Point.png to be in https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/images/Point.png

Comment: Note how the URL is relative to the `leaflet.css` file. Approaches include (a) specifying absolute URLs (b) hosting the Leaflet files yourself and provide URLs relative to those.

Comment: I host the Leaflet folder, do you mean I must put the .png in the same folder than leaflet.css ?

Comment: You might be hosting it already, but something is pointing to https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/ .

Comment: Culprit is the line (from other similar question): `<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>`